# How to change grease pencil texture Blender 2.8

Tags: animation, texturing, node-editor, grease-pencil, 2d

So I've been looking around and I can't find anywhere on how to change the look of grease pencil strokes to make custom brushes. All I could find was this link
https://code.blender.org/2018/07/grease-pencil-status-update/
where it clearly shows that you can create a different texture, but I've played around with the materials and adding a texture to the stroke in the surface options and I can't get the result I want. Has this option not been added yet or does someone know how to achieve this effect?